In Texas, can they turn you away from the ballot box for your t-shirt?
Today I went to vote. I was told I couldn't vote with my t-shirt, which had a political statement on it that included the call to "abandon" one of the candidates by name.
Is there a law that prevents you from wearing such "political t-shirts" at the ballot box?

In a country where handing water to a voter waiting in line, without any messaging, is seen as "too much influence", you really have to ask this question?

@nvoigt I live in the state that you are referring to. Please don't believe the media hype. This year we are having record breaking early voting-again. The whole point of the law was to let the poll workers take care of anyone that might be in a line.

Most states have laws or policies which prevent political advertisements or electioneering near polling places.  Texas rules say:

Each early voting and election day polling place must be organized
with 100-foot distance markers posted at surrounding outside entrances
to the building.  During the voting period and inside this protected
area, it is prohibited to electioneer, including expressing preference
for or against any candidate, measure, or political party.  A
violation of this provision in the Election Code is a Class C
misdemeanor.

So yes, anyone can be turned away from a polling place for a shirt that advocates a specific political position. And if they make too much trouble over it, they can be arrested.
I think the idea is that polling places are the final act in voting, and so electioneers might become particularly desperate and aggressive in last-ditch efforts to secure votes. Blocking electioneering in a 100 foot radius keeps polling place tempers cool.

Ironically, four days after I posted this answer this happened when a man going to vote early in South Carolina wore a Trump merch hat into the polling station. Case in point… (pardon the liberal-slant 'cast; it was hard to find an unedited clip without commentator overlay).

Further to this, it appears in Texas case law has decided "a person may not wear apparel or a similar communicative device relating to a candidate, measure, or political party appearing on the ballot in the current election under Section 61.010, but a person may wear such apparel relating to a candidate, measure, or political party that does not appear on the ballot in the current election." per https://www.sos.state.tx.us/elections/laws/advisory2023-01.shtml and the references therein, so "Free Palistine!" might be ok without the reference to Harris.

@origimbo: You may be right, but I'd avoid political slogans. Whether or not to turn you are away will be a judgement call by the site administrator. It's a coin flip, and arguing over the decision can get you arrested, so maybe not the brightest approach...

It kind of surprises me that any reasonably politically active American could be ignorant of electioneering restrictions. Based on what I have seen of American voting locations across various states, there is always a ring of supporters and signs for various candidates at around 100 feet from the polling location (and none closer than that).

Of course, it wouldn't surprise me that certain freedom of speech hardliners (or people engaging in special pleading for being able to advocate for their positions in particular) might oppose such rules (and there are arguments the other way), but it's surprising to see that there are politically active people who are not aware of them at all.

Actually, there is a weird angle to that rule: I once had, as an election official, to turn away a candidate coming in to vote, because he wore a t-shirt with his own face on it (and indicating he was a candidate). Essentially, he was allowed to show his face in the polling station, but only the corporal one, not a printed replica...

If you have nothing else to wear, and it's not too cold, are you allowed to take the t-shirt of and vote topless? If yes, is that different for men and women? (Just read about the alternative - wear the t-shirt inside out).

@gnasher729: If one only has one shirt, and that shirt has a political slogan on it, and one cannot buy, beg, or steal another shirt before the election… Sounds like a case for Vote by Mail. And maybe intervention by a social worker…

@gnasher729 Topless voting was done in 2020.  And I know there was another woman who took her T-shirt off in order to vote this week, but she wasn't topless underneath.

Fun fact: the mayoral election in the very small German town my family lives in almost had to be repeated because of a single sign outside of a single polling station. However, the courts struck down the complaint because a) the plaintiff made a formal mistake, b) the plaintiff had no standing, c) even if the plaintiff had standing, the complaint had no merit, and d), there was no harm demonstrated – to change the outcome of the election, more than 25% of people who voted for the winning candidate in this particular station would have to have been influenced by the sign, which is unrealistic,

… especially considering that the ratio of votes in this particular station matched closely with every other polling station in the city which did not have an offending sign within their neutral perimeter. Also interesting is that the old mayor kept governing the city during the 6 month the court case took until it was decided, which was not without its own controversy. He claimed, he had a duty to run the city until the next mayor is sworn in, but that view was contested. Anyway, everything resolved when the courts rendered their final decision and the winner was sworn in.

@TedWrigley If I’m refused access to the polling station, it’s most likely a physical impossibility to vote by mail. And I’m not in the habit of carrying a spare shirt with me in case my shirt offends. Doesn’t matter if there are thirty shirts in my wardrobe.

@gnasher729: Liberty entails responsibility. Deal with it…

@TedWrigley There is responsibility that votes get counted, Deal with it. I don't like your shoes by the way. Go change them. I don't like your skin colour either. Deal with it. My response to "deal witjh it" is "f*** them".

@gnasher729: That is precisely the response I expect from someone who demands liberty but refuses to take responsibility for it. There are rules we all have to obey to keep things civil in the world. If you think a rule is a bad rule, work to change it. Break it even, if you think you can challenge it effectively in court. But don't huff and puff because the rule is inconvenient and thus shouldn't apply to you. The fact is we all must deal with it. We can deal with it like adults, or like children; we can deal with it as free men or from jail cells.  Choose your flavor of responsibility.

Anecdotally, at my local polling place today (Election Day) - There was a very visible chalk line on the sidewalk, at the limit. "This far! No farther!"

Yes.
According to Chapter 85: Conduct of Voting by Personal Appearance:

Sec. 85.036.  ELECTIONEERING.  (a)  During the time an early voting polling place is open for the conduct of early voting, a person may not electioneer for or against any candidate, measure, or political party in or within 100 feet of an outside door through which a voter may enter the building or structure in which the early voting polling place is located.

Go home, change your shirt, and vote.

I just turned it inside out in the bathroom. What a stupid rule though. I can't think of any other place on public property where you could be restricted from wearing a shirt. I thought the law was always and everywhere with regard to shirts  that the person looking could always "avert their eyes".

@EvanCarroll making sure people aren't influenced by anyone inside the voting center is more important than respecting your rights to free speech in that place.

@EvanCarroll Public voting places have been deemed to be not subject to public property rules, via multiple court decisions, even when they obviously are public property.

There are similar rules in NJ as I found when I ran for office. We weren't allowed to try and persuade anyone within 100' of the door of the voting location (and trust me, we measured). Furthermore, if we handed out any literature to voters, they were required to stow it in either a pocket or bag once within the 100' radius.

@max While I can go along with the sentiment, the reality is that a shirt worn inside will have less impact than the campaign workers X feet from the polling station (where X is the legally allowed minimum distance). When I went to early vote earlier in the week (ended up deciding to wait until voting day because of the long lines), while I was in line, I could see the Trump and the Harris campaign tents, but I didn't notice what shirts anyone in line was wearing.

Apparently yes. See Election Advisory No. 2024-06: RE Certain Activities in Vicinity of Polling Places.
Also my best guess as to why that is the case would probably be about voter intimidation and thus voter suppression. Other regulations for example also include the ban of weapons around poling places (except for police etc; even if the state is otherwise open carry) or the prohibition of use of lots of electronic devices including cell phones that are very common and far from being illegal objects almost anywhere.
Like it's not hard to imagine a group of armed brown shirts or respectively red hats in the U.S. context (not sure Harris/Walz has comparable levels of collective uniformation) to "police" a ballot box cheering those who sport their gang colors and harassing those who don't or self-acclaimed "election watchers" who corrupt the secrecy of the vote and/or record "political enemies" or other such antidemocratic measures.
Those are literally election interference and irregularities that happen in other countries and it's a high value that people in a democracy can cast their vote free, safe and secretly.
So that has probably less to do with messages being offensive and more to do with the fact that a voting place might be a bottleneck and that political groups (of any side) blocking access to that place would be a massive interference with the democratic process.
Apparently that also just relates to the immediate vicinity of the voting place (~30m or 100 feet) outside of which you could again wear that t-shirt (whether that makes sense is another issue)

Right, voter intimidation in polling places is something that has a long history in the southern USA. And clothing is actually a particularly sensitive issue here, because a bunch of individuals in white robes and hoods liked to show up and intimidate Black voters with their mere presence. I'm actually a bit sympathetic to the "freedom of expression" position here, but one should be aware of the possible consequences: getting rid of such rules would allow for intimidation of non-conforming voters (and "don't vote for Harris" is not precisely a non-conforming position in Texas).
