What constitutes "campaigning" in a polling place?
As far as I know, campaigning is not allowed at a polling station and within a certain radius around them. How strict is it what counts as campaigning in that context? For example, from what a news report I just watched, it looked to me as if one of the candidates of a current election cast their vote while wearing a piece of clothing prominently showing their catchphrase campaign slogan (apparently without any consequences).
On the one hand, a candidate can hardly avoid showing e.g. their face which is the same as on their ads. On the other hand, I suppose that anybody else would be asked to remove or cover such a slogan.

Do you have an example to show this happening?

Electioneering laws differ from state to state. And whether clothing is specifically mentioned varies. See https://www.kslegresearch.org/KLRD-web/Publications/ElectionsEthics/electioneering-distances_2022-update.pdf

I specifically tried not to stir things up by not specifying who it was, but here you go: https://youtu.be/Rjd3UeJESic?si=VHRVnD6ddkICWHIP This seems to be in immediate vicinity of the polling place, though strictly speaking I cannot tell from the footage with full confidence whether it is perhaps just outside the required radius and iwhether the head was was put on only after leaving that radius

This is important to know as has been mentioned the laws vary from state to state and depending on which candidate you are asking about they could be showing up with a large security detail and practically closing down the polling location while they vote so a few campaign slogans are not going to matter as much.

It should probably be noted that anyone under secret service protection and getting massive media coverage going to polls is likely going to turn into a circus and become an exception to the rule as they become a walking advertisement.

Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/105712/in-texas-can-they-turn-you-away-from-the-ballot-box-for-your-t-shirt

Clothing depends on the specific state's statutes, elections board policy, and case law surrounding it.
A table prepared in 2022 by the Kansas Legislative Research Department mentioned in another question gives an overview.
For example, Virginia is listed as

Voter may wear apparel, sticker, or button on which candidate name or political slogan appears

and Maine is very specific

Voter may wear button not exceeding 3 inches any dimension.

Florida has no restrictions on clothing.

“Voters may wear campaign buttons, shirts, hats, or any other campaign items when they enter the polling place to vote. Voters may not otherwise campaign there.” (From the Polling Place Procedures Manual incorporated within Rule 1S-2.034, Florida Administrative Code)


Ah, okay. Florida is applicable here, so nothing wrong. Thanks
